# Git 2.4.3 installation

Tags: git, installation

Ferdi@mail

```
~/Downloads/git-2.4.3 $ apt-get install git-2.4.3  
Reading package lists... Error!  
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_olivia_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: This is not related to Git but is an Ubuntu problem, see http://askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git
```

It should update and upgrade your install database so you will be able to install latest git version